# Error in sei^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator, in metafor

Tags: error-handling, standard-error

I'm trying to run a fixed effect meta analysis, using SMDs and the SE with `metafor`. I'm using an `rma.uni-function`:

```
metafor::rma.uni(yi="SMD12", sei="SE12",  data=SMDpainmeta, method="FE")
```

`R` gives me the following error message:

> Error in sei^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

I set `SE12`, which is the standard error at 12 months as the `sei` value. The values are clearly numeric, although some `NAN` values are also present in this column.

When I use the `vi` value and set the corresponding Variance instead of `SE12`

```
metafor::rma.uni(yi="SMD12", vi="Variance12", method="FE", data=SMDpainmeta)
```

I get the follow error:

> error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
>     NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

So either way there seems to be a problem with my `NAN` values, which are a result of my missing data in this studies at timepoint 12.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the variable names in quotes. So, just use:

```
rma.uni(yi=SMD12, sei=SE12, data=SMDpainmeta, method="FE")
```